# How to find last number (in a row) for a certain variable using excel

Tags: excel, variables, numbers, find

The implementation include a lot of data. For simple example in this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ3ca.jpg) I should be able to find the last number in the row either "500" for "Amy", "700" for "Sam", etc.

Kindly need all your help to figure this out.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The following formula entered as array formula (by using Ctrl+Shift+Enter) could be used:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$9,MAX(($A$2:$A$9=E2)*(ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1)))
```

For F2, where the last amount for Amy is being calculated:

`($A$2:$A$9=E2)` returns an array of True and False for those that match `Amy`

`(ROW($A$2:$A$9)-ROW($A$2)+1)` gives an array for the rows in the dataset. `$A$2:$A$9` is the range for the names, `$A$2` is the first name in the dataset.

The two above multipled together gives the row numbers in which `Amy` was found.

`MAX()` then gives the highest row number, which is used by INDEX to retrieve the Amount matching this row number.

Comment: Thank you for you help Jerry, anyways is it possible to change the $C$2:$C$9 to $C:$C? because the data entry is quite frequent.

Comment: @CynthiaAnggraeni Yes, you will however have to change the other references as well. `$A$2:$A$9` to `$A:$A` and `$A$2` to `$A$1`.